# session validation in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

Short version-display home page only if session is already created

### Details

I have a `login.html`. It links to `validation.jsp`. It checks for password and then redirects to the following page.

But I want that this following page to be displayed only when the
 validation is true. Otherwise if someone enters the link to the page
 and finds that the page has not been logged into, it will prompt to
 do it so.

It worked fine in the servlet. I created a new session in validation page
 and set `request.getSession(false)` in the home page.

but this doesnt seem to work in jsp. If I set `session=false` in the page
 directive, then I can not access session object at all. and if I
 explicitly do what I have done in the page, it still doesn't work!!

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.io.*"
        contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"
        import="java.util.*;"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>


        <%


    session=request.getSession(false);

    if(session==null)
    {
        out.println("please login");


    }

    else
    { 
        out.println("how did it run!!! ??");
        out.println(application.getAttribute("one"));
        out.println(session.isNew());
        out.println(session.getId());

        out.println("<form action='logout.jsp' method='post'>");
        out.println("<input type='submit'>");
        out.println("</form>");

    } 

    %>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It would be better not to check on the existence of a session but rather on a specific attribute being present (e.g. user token). This way you have more control.

Comment: oh..like setting an attribute via session and then checking it on the home page?

Comment: Like setting an attribute when the user logs in (removing it when he logs out) and then indeed check it on the homepage. There are a bunch of frameworks (shiro, spring security) that can do this for you by the way.

Comment: seems viable.springs hibernate will follow once i am done with jsp

Comment: thanks though..will try this after dinner

Comment: but shouldn;t setting `session="false"` in the directive mean this 

`session=request.getSession(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use `if(session==null)` to determine if someone is logged in. Sessions are generally created automatically, and besides, you might want to use a session for something even before login.  You check for a specific session attribute.

```
String userid = (String)session.getAttribute("userid");
if(userid!=null)
{
    out.print("logged in as:" + userid);
}
```

Of course in the login code you have to set it:

```
session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
```

There is also no need to call `request.getSession` in JSP. In a servlet you would need to, but in JSP the `session` object is already populated with `request.getSession` for you.

Edit:

When you do the session=false directive then the session object isn't declared so you'll need not just to set it but actually *declare* it: `HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);` Then you will get session=null, but its dangerous to rely on this for security, as going to a page where you didn't set session=false will create the session, and your code will then think someone was validly logged in, when they were not. Even if you are certain that you put session=false everywhere, you might miss a spot, or more likely, the next developer after you will not understand you did it this way, and a security disaster is just waiting to happen.

Using session=false is intended for performance boost not security. E.g. you have a faq page that doesn't care about sessions, set session=false so people going to that link doesn't create sessions and waste memory.

Comment: yeah..i got it working with sessionAttributes..
the guy from the comments helped me towards it
..

Comment: what i dint get is session=false...doesnt it mean getSession(false)!!1

Comment: it should but did you put that in every page? if not, the session was created already by an earlier page.

Comment: i did wat i did during servlets.created a session once during validation.then on every page disabled the option to create new session by getSession(false)..this way u could view the pages only if u went through validation and a session was created

Comment: but here if i set session=false , then the session object becomes unavailable! ..i get red line under it in eclipse...so cant check anything on it !

Comment: I've moved my last few comments to the answer itself.

Comment: bang on.i've understood what i was doing wrong.silly me.

Answer (score 0):

A `JSP` creates a session by default. If you don't need session then use following

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```